# PHP/mail : server sends email originating from wrong domain

Tags: php, email, domain, email-server

I have a Mediatemple dv (Plesk) server with two domains, each has static IP.

I had domain1 as main domain and domain2 as secondary.

When A PHP script from domain2 sends email the headers show the IP address of domain1 as the origin.
Received: from domain2.com (domain1.com [70.ipof domain1]).

I want only domain2 to be mentioned so I did the following:

Changed server name to domain2.com
made domain2.com the primary domain (about 30 hours ago)
made fixed IP address of domain2.com the default address for the server.

Still when the script sends emails I see the same info as above in the header.

What do I need to do to make the email origin domain2.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to define reverse DNS http://www.ntchosting.com/dns/reverse-dns.html

Answer (score 0):

reset hostname, reset php and mail server. Actually you can reset everything related to web services, if that doesn't help then grep /etc for domain1 and wipe it, then reset again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/advanced-email-php

Also verify the `sendmail_path` in the `php.ini`, and then check the sendmail executable's config file too.